# Use of an overloaded global class in a Symfony controller

Tags: symfony, overloading

I try to include the following code in a Symfony controller file:

```
namespace {
    class LocalSoapClient extends \SoapClient {
        function __doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version) {
            //...............
        }
    }
}
namespace .....\Controller {
    //.......
}
```

In the controller class, I try to use the overloaded class:

```
$service = new \LocalSoapClient($wsdl);
```

With the \, the class is supposed to be in the global namespace. But I get the error:

```
Class 1\LocalSoapClient does not exist in .......\FrontBundle/Controller/
```

Why?

If I use a single namespace instruction, and I overload the class before the Controller class, I get the same kind of error.

What can I do to be able to use my overloaded class?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you feel the need to have LocalSoapClient be defined in a global namespace?  Are you trying to use it from a different controller as well?  Your posted looks like it should work.  You obviously simplified things for this question and it's possible you have a typo.  The 1 in "Class 1\LocalSoapClient" is very confusing,  Consider copy/pasting the exact error message and code.  In any event, LocalSoapClient should probably be a service.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 DON’Ts that you’re violating:

1. DON’T put more than one class into one file.
2. DON’T mix namespaces. Reason is, Symfony uses PSR-0/-4 autoloading and what you’re trying to do cannot work.

The solution is to simply create separate files with proper namespaces.

Put the following into `src/Your/SomethingBundle/Soap` (or wherever you like the file to live):

```
<?php

namespace Your\SomethingBundle\Soap;

class LocalSoapClient extends \SoapClient 
{
    // …
}
```

And your controller should just look like this:

```
<?php

namespace Your\SomethingBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Your\SomethingBundle\Soap\LocalSoapClient;

class MyController extends Controller
{
    public function myAction()
    {
        $soapClient = new LocalSoapClient();
        // …
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm new to Symfony, but I was assuming that general PHP principles such as the use of \ to access the global namespace were still applicable.

Comment: Yes, \ for global classes works. However, You have mixed namespaces within a file, and this is discouraged. To be honest, I don’t know what exactly Symfony’s PSR-0 implementation does to resolve namespaces, but this type of code usually involves a lot of magic. Anyway, you should always put each class in a separate file, and the filepath should always match the namespace. *Especially* if you are new to Symfony.